# Python Dictionary JSON Key, Val Extraction

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm having a hard time understanding what is going on with this walmart API and I can't seem to iterate through key, values like I wish. I get different errors depending on the way I attack the problem.

```
import requests
import json
import urllib

response=requests.get("https://grocery.walmart.com/v0.1/api/stores/4104/departments/1256653758154/aisles/1256653758260/products?count=60&start=0")
info = json.loads(response.text)
print(info)
```

1. I'm not sure if I'm playing with a dictionary or a JSON object.
2. I'm thrown off because the API itself has no quotes over key/val.
3. When I do a json.loads it comes in but only comes in with single quotes.

I've tried going at it with for-loops but can only traverse the top layer and nothing else. My overall goal is to retrieve the info from the API link, turn it into JSON and be able to grab which ever key/val I need from it.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure if I'm playing with a dictionary or a JSON object.

Python has no concept of a "JSON Object". It's a dictionary.

> I'm thrown off because the API itself has no quotes over key/val.

Yes it does

`{"aisleName":"Organic Dairy, Eggs & Meat","productCount":17,"products":[{"data":`

> When I do a json.loads it comes in but only comes in with single quotes

Because it's a Python dictionary, and the `repr()` of `dict` uses single quotes.

Try `print(info['aisleName'])` for example

Comment: I'm not seeing the double quotes when using chrome extension jsonView.
print(info['aisleName']) works but how do I traverse further down?

Comment: You may read any tutorial on python dictionaries. `products = data['products']`... `for p in products: #do_something`